# Set empty value on number column using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am trying to assign "Column A" value to "Column B" in another list. Both columns are of "Number" data type.

When nothing is entered in Column A, Column is getting set as "0". How can I show empty in Column B also.

PS - I am not allowed to change the datatype of Column B

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a number column type in List B it is taking null value as 0. You can modify the column type as Single Text type column or try to Put the condition in List B that if it is 0 set it as

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Ankit. I missed a point there. Many calculations and reports are based on that column and i am not allowed to change it to Single line of text.. And for your second point, if it is 0, setting the column to empty is not happening. It always goes to 0.

Comment: Any Suggestions

Comment: ok can you have another column created with similar name almost of single line text type and keep the original one hidden. Now you can set the logic that if the hidden one is 0 set the newly created one to be &nbsp;. In this way, User wont be confused.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like, and this is very generalized...

1. Create workflow variable of type number callled NullNum
2. Do not set it to anything
3. Check if Column A is empty
4. If it is, set Column B to workflow variable NullNum
5. If it is not, set Column B to Column A

Comment: When I tried this (with an SP2010 workflow) it set the field as 0 instead of null (blank).